# Show that any sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that (...) does not converge to any limit with respect to the sunflower metric.

Tags: limits, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Working in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with two metrics, the standard (Euclidean) and the sunflower metric:

\begin{equation}
d_{sf}=\begin{cases} 
\lVert x-y \rVert & \text{if x and y lie on the same line through the origin} \\
\lVert x \rVert + \lVert y \rVert & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I have shown that given a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, if it converges in the sunflower metric to $x$ $\Rightarrow$ it converges in the euclidean metric to $x$, and given a counterexample to show $\not\Leftarrow$ (if it converges in the euclidean metric to $x$, it doesn't necessarily converge to $x$ in the sunflower metric. However, I need to show that any sequence that converges in the euclidean metric to $x$ and not in the sunflower metric to $x$, does not converge to any limit with respect to the sunflower metric, and I just don't know where to start and how to approach and say in a general way that it does not converge at all.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.  "... does not converge to any limit with respect to the sunflower metric": but you just said it does not converge in the sunflower metric.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. By definition (for any metric), a sequence does not converge iff it does not converge to any limit.

Comment: Just for fun, my guess is that what is wanted is to show that no sequence that converges under euclid but not under sunflower has a sunflower-convergent subsequence. Let's see what the OP comes back with.

Comment: Thank you all for your patience, I edited the question since it was a matter of convergence to a certain $x$, and say that if it does not converge to that $x$, it does not converge at all, but I still feel stuck.

Comment: Just to make it clear, is what you're trying to prove equivalent to "it is not possible for $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ to converge to $x$ in the Euclidean metric and to $x' \not= x$ in the sunflower metric"?

Comment: No, what I would have to prove is that if a sequence converges in the euclidean metric to $x$ and not to $x$ in the sunflower metric, then it doesn't converge at all.

Comment: @AlexA.G. I'm assuming you mean "doesn't converge at all in the sunflower metric" otherwise the statement is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something about the sunflower metric which can be useful for your question, and for the sunflower metric in general:

First, some notation. For $x\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, let $\ell_x = \{\, kx : k \in \mathbb R\,\}$ denote the infinite straight line through the origin and $x$. For $x,x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots\in\mathbb R^{2}$, we write $x_n \xrightarrow{Euclid} x$ if $x_n$ converges to $x$ in the Euclidean metric, and $x_n \xrightarrow{sun} x$ if $x_n$ converges to $x$ in the sunflower metric.

> **Lemma.** Let $x, x_1,x_2,x_2,\dots\in\mathbb R^{2}$. Then $x_n \xrightarrow{sun} x$ if and only if $x_n \xrightarrow{Euclid} x$ and either one of the following hold:
>
> (1) $x = (0, 0)$, or
>
> (2) $x_n \in \ell_x$ for all but finitely many $n$.

*Proof.* Suppose $x_n \xrightarrow{sun} x$. If $x = (0,0)$ then this convergence is just convergence in the usual Euclidean sense. Now suppose that $x \neq (0,0)$. If there exists an infinite subsequence $x_{n_j}$ of $x_n$ such that $x_{n_j} \notin \ell_x$ for all $j$, then $d_{sun}(x_{n_j}, x) = \|x_{n_j}\| + \|x\| \geq \|x\| > 0$ and so $x_{n_j} \not \xrightarrow{sun} x$, which is a contradiction. Thus there exists some $N$ such that for all $n > N$ we have $x_n \in \ell_x$. Then $x_n \xrightarrow{Euclid} x$ as well, because on $\ell_x$ distance is measured just like in the Euclidean metric.

The converse is clearly true, also arguing that for $x = 0$ or on $\ell_x$, convergence of $x_n$ to $x$ in the two metrics is the same. $\square$

In particular, we cannot have $x_n \xrightarrow{Euclid} x$ and $x_n \xrightarrow{sun} y$ if $y \neq x$.

Answer (score 1):

You have actually already proven a statement which is equivalent to your last question, namely that if

$$x_n\to x$$
In the sunflower metric then $$x_n\to x$$ in the normal metric.

This statement and what you are asking are equivalent in arbitrary metric spaces, here is the proof:

> Claim: given a metric space $X$ with two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$, then
> $$\forall x_n\forall_x\left[\left(x_n\to x\right)_2 \implies \left(x_n\to x\right)_1\right]$$
> If and only if
> $$\forall x_n\forall_x \left[ \left[ (x_n\to x)_1 \land \neg(x_n\to x)_2 \right]\implies \forall y[\neg (x_n\to y)_2]\right]$$

Some clarification on the notation:
$$(x_n\to x)_1$$
Means the sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$ with the metric $d_1$

That second statement in the proof, if you are confused by the logical notation would translate to "If $x_n\to x$ with $d_1$, but not $d_2$, then $x_n$ does not converge with $d_2$.

**Proof of forward direction:** first we assume that for any sequence $x_n$, if $(x_n\to x)_2$ then $(x_n\to x)_1$. Now assume that $x_n$ is some sequence such that $(x_n\to x)_1$ but not $(x_n\to x)_2$, then suppose $(x_n\to y)_2$ for some $y$, but then by our first assumption, $(x_n\to y)_1$ and since limits are unique, this means $y=x$, contradicting our assumption that $x_n$ does not converge to $x$ with $d_2$. This proves the forward direction.

**Proof of reverse direction:** we assume $$\forall x_n\forall_x \left[ \left[ (x_n\to x)_1 \land \neg(x_n\to x)_2 \right]\implies \forall y[\neg (x_n\to y)_2]\right]$$

Now given a sequence $x_n$ such that $(x_n\to x)_2$, then since $x_n$ *does* converge with $d_2$, we must have $$\neg[(x_n\to x)_2\land \neg(x_n\to x)_1]$$

Which is equivalent to

$$\neg(x_n\to x)_2\lor (x_n\to x)_1$$
But we already know that $(x_n\to x)_2$, hence for the above statement to be true we need $(x_n\to x)_1$, concluding the proof.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @AlexA.G. See if it makes sense first before thanking me...but no worries, it is a fun question, if there's too much, the section "**proof of forward direction**" is all you really need